# Select text again after execCommand execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, execcommand

I'm building a text editor using jQuery.

I have a content-editable `div` and when I click the `<span id="bold-text">`
I can change the style of selected text:

```
$('span#bold-text').mousedown(function(e){
    document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
});
```

After execution of `document.execCommand` (or maybe because clicking) span selection loose focus.

How can I auto select same text after `execCommand`?

Comment: Try $("span#bold-text").focus()

Comment: That's not gonna work because i need to focus on last selected text not the span.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to store the last focused item within jQuery (exclude the span):

```
var toFocus;
$("*:not(span#bold-text)").blur(function() {
  toFocus = this;
});
```

Then re-focus it:

```
$('span#bold-text').click(function(e){        
  document.execCommand('bold', false, null);    
  if(toFocus){
    $(toFocus).focus(); 
  }        
});
```